# Faculty application: getting a recommendation letter from a professor at the same university

Tags: faculty-application

I am applying for an assistant professor position at a university. I have worked with a faculty member there for a long time - he was a postdoc in my PhD lab and I have been in touch with him later. He is one of my references in all other applications, but I am not quite sure how the search committee of his university would feel about his reference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: An inside reference? That’s probably the best one you could have!

Comment: I assume you mean "faculty search committee" instead of "admissions committee"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask him about the appropriateness (as well as his willingness) of his writing a letter. I think that in most cases it wouldn't be a problem, but he would then, possibly, need to abstain from further official participation in your application to avoid conflict issues.

Since you were never his superior, there are no real issues that I can see.